# CoffeeScript JSDoc support in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: coffeescript, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

Is there a way to use JSDoc to annotate source code written in CoffeeScript when working in PhpStorm/WebStorm? When working in the IDE, it is very helpful to be able to use JSDoc to have proper code completion for functions.

I found this past question: [How to document CoffeeScript source code with JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833021/how-to-document-coffeescript-source-code-with-jsdoc) However, the answers and comments are not clear on whether it is supported or what the proper syntax is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported. Pleasze feel free to file a request for this feature to [youtrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated answer for anyone who comes across this thread in the future. WebStorm 2017.3 (the current version as of this writing) has support for CoffeeScript javadocs.

The basic syntax is this:

```
###*
 * Here is a simple description for foo
 * @param {Bar} bar - Some parameter to foo
 * @returns {Object} The thing that foo returns
###
foo = (bar) ->
```

WebStorm will give you the documentation when you press ctrl+Q.

Answer (score -2):

in coffeescript there is a way to use basic javascript by including code between "`"

```
coffee code
` common javascript code `
coffee code
```

there is maybe a possibility to use this to put your jsCode here

```
coffee code
` 
/** @constructor*/ 
`
coffee code
```

I did not tried yet that solution...